# Updating GitHub repo with less files

Tags: git, github, repository

I committed to my github repo using the terminal commands:

```
git add .
git commit -m
git push raytracer master
```

It was going well for about 15-20 commits, until I restructured my code and deleted about 2-3 header files and combined them into one. Now when I do the same commands, it yells at me and I'm guessing its because it's expecting files that I deleted after the restructuring.

What are the proper commands for me to successfully commit my local repo to github?

Comment: Which command "yells at" you, and what's the exact error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you deleted some files manually (not using `git rm`) git is not going to be happy. But, fear not, it is easy to fix.

Use `git status` and see which files git is missing. If you really want them gone, you need to tell git by using `git rm <files_or_dirs_to_remove>`. You may need to type full file name of deleted file (not using wildcards like *), and may need to add `-f` switch to force git to remove it from index (actually, add remove intent to index).

After that, you should be able to `git commit` your changes. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to use the `git remove` command to remove these files from tracking. git will not automatically realize that you intended to remove the file; you need to tell it that you no longer wish for those files to be a part of the repository. See the [man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rm.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

i think `git` like `svn` might have a special `rm` to remove a file from the repository as well. You can try to revert the deletion of the files and run `git rm` instead of plain `rm` to delete the files